# Redis.LRANGE returning list but not how i need it too

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am storing a large amount of data in redis and caching it, then when i need it i basically using lrange to fetch the data and send it to my front end the problem is when it returns it, it is returning it in the format like below:

[image: Current Format]

But I need it to be returned in the format as follow:

[image]

Why is the lrange function putting the "" in front of each object? This is the current lrange function:

```
function rangeReturn(callback) {
      client.lrange("Historial_Price: " + ticker, 0, -1, (err, reply) => {
        if (!err) {
          callback(reply);
        } else {
          console.log("Error within client.lrange in Quandl.js");
        }
      });
    }

//If there is already data stored
    if (listIsTrue) {
      //Return the data to the front end
      rangeReturn(function (reply) {
        console.log(reply)
        return res.send(reply);
      });
    }
```

Comment: It is being returned as a string. Try using `JSON.parse(reply);`. This should turn it back into an object.

Comment: @JayHales Im getting unexpected token with JSON.parse, im assuming because reply is actually and array of JSONs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate through each response and parse each item with `JSON.parse()`.

```
function rangeReturn(callback) {
    client.lrange("Historial_Price: " + ticker, 0, -1, (err, reply) => {
        if (!err) {
            callback(reply);
        } else {
            console.log("Error within client.lrange in Quandl.js");
        }
    });
}

var correctValues = [];

//If there is already data stored
if (listIsTrue) {
    //Return the data to the front end
    rangeReturn(function(reply) {

        reply.forEach(value => {
           correctValues.push(JSON.parse(value));
        });

        // Do whatever with correctValues from here on.

        console.log(reply)
        return res.send(reply);
    });
}
```